Ghidra user scripts location
Ghidra: what is default location (path) for custom scripts? Same question for custom .fidb files.

When you create your first Ghidra Script from the script manager, Ghidra will ask you where it should store the script, so there is no "default path"; but note that if you left the path empty, it will automatically create (if not preexistent) a folder $USER_HOME/ghidra_scripts and store the script in it.
Also note that you can access a list of all known paths by right-clicking a script -> "Script Directories"
I never used .fidb but according to https://github.com/threatrack/ghidra-fidb-repo# you should store them in ~/git/ghidra.bin/Ghidra/Features/FunctionID/src/main/fidb

I use pre-built Ghidra binary, not built from source, there are no such path: ~/git/ghidra.bin/Ghidra/Features/FunctionID/src/main/fidb. My path is ../ghidra_11.1.1_PUBLIC/Ghidra/Features/FunctionID/ that contains: data, ghidra_scripts,lib.
